# How can I set frame title to include Babel language when point is in a block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, talon

My frame title is currently set as `(setq frame-title-format '(buffer-file-name "%f" ("%b")))`, or for example `/path/to/file.org`. I'd like to set my frame title to include the language name of the Babel block, if the point is within a block.

For example if I move the point inside a `#+begin_src python` block, then the frame title would be `/path/to/file : python`, and reset to `/path/to/file` when the point leaves that block.

Reason: I'm trying to use 3rd-party software (Talon voice) that has support for different vocabularies. It selects vocabularies based on the app, or the window title. I'd like to automatically load and unload Python support, for example, if I'm in a `#+BEGIN_SRC jupyter-python` block or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not beautiful, but may work well enough for you.

```
(defun set-frame-title ()
  (setq frame-title-format 
    (if (org-in-src-block-p)
        (format "%s - %s" (buffer-file-name) (org-element-property :language (org-element-context)))
      (buffer-file-name))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'set-frame-title)
```

if performance is not good, you can look into cursor-sensor-functions. This is a lot more invasive though, and you have to hook into font-lock to get all the properties set up I think.

Comment: Works well. No noticeable performance issue. This is *great*. Now I can say "list a b c"  and if I'm in an elisp block, Emacs prints `(a b c)` and if I'm in a python block it prints `[a, b, c]`. :).

Comment: That is pretty cool (both the answer and the use case)!